# Change Listview textsize with seekbar using custom layout

Tags: android, listview, seekbar

I have a listview with a seekbar at the bottom, the purpose of seekbar is to adjust the textsize of listview, my listview has a custom layout, the textview there is my target when adjusting the textsize. I solved this, but when I'm sliding the seekbar, only the 1st, 4th, 7th row's text is changed.

```
 seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        int Blast;
        @Override

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

            TextView shopName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_version);
            prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
          ed.putFloat("fontsize", ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_version)).getTextSize());
            ed.commit();

           // myList.setSelection(1);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_version)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, seekBar.getProgress());

        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_version)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,seekBar.getProgress());
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser){

                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_version)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,progress);

            Blast = progress;

        }
    });

public void viewAll1(){

        Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllData2();

        String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.item_version};

        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter =
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, cursor, from, to, 0);

    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

}
```

item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/item_version"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:typeface="serif"

    android:paddingStart="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you need to reload listview to see the affect properly.

Comment: thank you for your response,. please guide me how to do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add this line after every setTextSize

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**EDIT:**

so the code would look like this:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter; // define the adapter above onCreate method

seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        int Blast;
        @Override

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

            TextView shopName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_version);
            prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
          ed.putFloat("fontsize", ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_version)).getTextSize());
            ed.commit();

           // myList.setSelection(1);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_version)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, seekBar.getProgress());
myCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_version)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,seekBar.getProgress());
myCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser){

                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_version)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,progress);
myCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Blast = progress;

        }
    });

public void viewAll1(){

        Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllData2();

        String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.item_version};

        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, cursor, from, to, 0);

    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

}
```

**EDIT2:**
you need to add setTextSize inside the getView of your custom adapter, since the notifyDataSetChange actually calls the getView method, this is a working example,but of course used a different type of adapter which is base adapter:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SeekBar seekbar;
    cursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    String str[]={"Shop Name"};
    ListView list;
    TextView tv;
    int globProg=20; //used default value for textsize 20 you can put anything else
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        seekbar= (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        myCursorAdapter= new cursorAdapter(MainActivity.this,str); 
        list.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            int Blast;

            @Override

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


                globProg= seekBar.getProgress(); //saving value in the global variable 
                myCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //this method calls the getview again so the view is recreated with the new size

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                globProg= seekBar.getProgress();
                myCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                          boolean fromUser) {
                globProg= seekBar.getProgress();
                myCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Blast = progress;

            }
        });

    }// end of onCreate 

    public class cursorAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        public String list[];
        Activity activity;

        public cursorAdapter(Activity activity,String list[]) {
            super();
            this.activity = activity;
            this.list = list;

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.length;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView textView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            LayoutInflater inflater =  activity.getLayoutInflater();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_version, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_version);
            holder.textView.setText(list[position]);
            holder.textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, globProg); // setTextSize here 
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            return convertView;
        }


    }






}
```

**EDIT3:**

```
public void viewAll1(){

        Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllData2();

        String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.item_version};
        int layoutid=R.layout.item_version;
        myCursorAdapter= new cursorAdapter(context ,  layoutid,cursor,from, to);
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

    }



public class cursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
        private Context appContext;
        private int layout;
        private Cursor mycursor;

        public cursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            this.appContext=context;
            this.layout=layout;
            this.mycursor=c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_version);
            String title = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( DBAdapter.KEY_NAME ) );
            textView.setText(title);
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, globProg);

        }



    }
```

Comment: Glad to help, it worked for me, plz accept it as answer if it works for your case :D thanks

Comment: you made a project like this? it still doesn't work :(

Comment: well not exactly same project, is your adapter a custom adapter? your listview contains 1 item or more? if more do you want to change text size for all of them?

Comment: please check out Edit 2 this is the code I tried :)

Comment: yes i it has multiple items and i want to change their text size, i used custom adapter

Comment: Thank you so much! can i use your code to connect to sqlite? my items in listview is from a database

Comment: well you can do the connection in a outer method and get the data in form of String array[]  then send the list to the adapter in my code, or use your cursor adapter but modify it, can you add your cursorAdapter code so I can help

Comment: Ok now i understand better :) i have a code that connects the sqlite to listview, (the viewAll1() method from above) my last problem is to connect that to the adapter

Comment: public void viewAll1(){

        Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllData2();

        String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.item_version};

        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter =
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, cursor, from, to, 0);

    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

}

Comment: ok check edit 3 in my answer above this is a custom cursor adapter :)

Comment: please accept my answer as the right answer if it helped you :)

Comment: No errors but the app is closing when viewAll1(); is called

Comment: add break points and debug your app and follow step by step to check what exception is giving you, and where exactly is the problem

Comment: String title=mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_NAME));   - this

Comment: this is database error, check out this link for help in database with custom cursor http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

Comment: without the getView, the database is filling the listview, but when i use the getView,. the app failed to start, just this one piece of code and we're done :) thanks to you, only 1 problem left

Comment: ok check this link and check the edit3 again, I modified the cursor adapter to become bindView instead of get view, if it still gives same error, then check the database column name

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/fmavhg/android-cursoradapter-with-custom-layout-and-how-to-use-it

Comment: getView works! :) one last problem, only the first data is shown in the listview

Comment: i removed this                                                                                                     Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }
        Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return 0;
        }
i managed to get all the data in listview..however it shows some duplicates and when i scroll down then scrolled up, different data is showing

Comment: problem solved! i use bindView! :) Thank you so much @NouranSAhmad you're a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your findViewById(R.id.item_version) is just finding one of the multiple R.id.item_version present in your layout (one for every element).

I would change approach like for example:

1) The SeekBar will modify and store/retrieve an activity scoped variable
2) In your Adapter getView you evaluate this variable to define the size of your TextView text.
3) When the Seekbar progress is changed: change the variable and call a notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response i'm new in android development :) can you look at my code in adapter? i've updated my codes above for you to see